# Selecting only the non existing data in another table

Tags: sql, join

I have table one which have an id column, and table2 which have same column

I want to select only the ids in table2 which are not present in table one. how to select that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join the two tables using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    table2 a
        LEFT JOIN table1 b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: `b.ID is NULL` when `a.ID does not exist` and this is what you want, try it `:)`

Comment: @Zaski b.ID is NULL when a LEFT JOIN is performed and there is no matching record (according to the ON clause) in the joined table.  a.ID exists but there is no matching b.ID in b.

Comment: You might also look into NOT IN and NOT EXISTS clauses which do a similar thing, although AFIAK these could be less efficient than a straight out NULL check as they require subqueries as opposed to a simple join.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at sql join queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it, using a subquery and IN.  The LEFT JOIN method already mentioned is probably more efficient, but IMO this method makes more semantic sense and is therefore easier to read.

```
SELECT t2.ID
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.ID NOT IN
(
   SELECT t1.ID
   FROM table1 t1
)
```